# Is there a way to check if a javascript object is empty in constant time?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I'm looking for a method for checking whether or not a javascript object has any properties on it, or not.  The solution I've often seen for this looks something like this:

```
var isObjectEmpty = function(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

However, I've discovered that, though this appears like it should operate in constant time (returning after one iteration in the for loop), it actually operates in linear time, at least in Chrome.  For an example, please observe this test:
  http://jsperf.com/empty-map-check-performance

Is anyone aware of a method for checking the emptiness of a javsacript object that will operate in constant time in all browsers?

Comment: Wow, the performance in Chrome is abysmal in that jsperf test, for both big and small maps. FF and IE do 10's of millions of ops/sec and Chrome does 1k for big maps, and 250k for small ones.

Comment: I wouldn't like to speculate on why Chrome is so abysmally slow on this test, but I have to ask: does it really matter? How much effort will you expend trying to 'fix' the Chrome problem, and how long will it take you to recover that time with increased performance? Don't micro-optimise until you show that you really have a problem.

Comment: Using `valueOf` gives me kind of uniform results (+ quicker): http://jsperf.com/empty-map-check-performance/2

Comment: @eithedog That only works in Webkit/Blink-based browsers I believe. It doesn't work in IE. Technically the result of `valueOf()` on an object is undefined. I'm pretty sure Firefox and IE both return `[Object object]` no matter what is in the object.

Comment: @Evan This may have something to do with checking keys in general in Chrome. I tried an alternate function using `Object.keys(map).length === 0` and got basically the exact same ops/sec.

Comment: @pseudosavant fair enough - haven't really tested this approach in other browsers (as Chrome in particular is in question); however, I'd think it's a step in right direction (unless we encounter an issue with edge cases) + can be altered to be cross-browser compliant. There's probably a good reason the check from OP is used in jquery though ;)

Comment: Really that isn't much slower than `valueOf`? I thought about trying it but wrote it off thinking that serializing large objects would be too slow.

Comment: @pseudosavant sorry - something weird is going on with jsperf (or i'm just not thinking at this hour; definitelly a couple of graphs doesn't show for me). Stringify is indeed slower.

Comment: @eithedog, I couldn't get the valueOf() method to work. It looks like Chrome just returns [Object object] as well:  [http://jsfiddle.net/n6txM/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/n6txM/1/)

Comment: @Evan oh, double fail then :( Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries - thanks for the feedback, all!  My search continues...